# Linker error in Mac

Tags: c++

I have a question regarding a piece of C++ code that I have been trying to compile in MacOS. Before I go ahead and explain my problem I should mention that I am very new to programming (actually a mathematician), and am trying to quickly understand someone's existing code to understand a problem -- and since I am new I am fairly lost. So any help is deeply appreciated. If the way I explain the problem is incorrect, (I apologise and) please tell me so I can change it appropriately.

I will not add the full code here since its too many files, but rather the final error when I try to compile it via the terminal. This code perfectly compiles on a linux but does not on my Mac.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Algorithm_langevin::compute_traj(gaussien&, input&, particle&)", referenced 
from:
_main in main-1aa316.o
"Algorithm_langevin::Algorithm_langevin(input&)", referenced from:
_main in main-1aa316.o
"input::load()", referenced from:
_main in main-1aa316.o
"gaussien::gaussien()", referenced from:
_main in main-1aa316.o
"particle::particle(input const&)", referenced from:
_main in main-1aa316.o
"vtable for hamiltonian_cg", referenced from:
hamiltonian_cg::hamiltonian_cg() in main-1aa316.o
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member 
function has no definition.
"vtable for hamiltonian_full", referenced from:
hamiltonian_full::hamiltonian_full() in main-1aa316.o
NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member 
function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As already mentioned, this code runs on linux machines but not on my Mac. Is this because there are some difference in standard library directories?

Again, I am really sorry if this question has been asked or has a simple answer. I would be grateful for any directions.

Comment: What is the command line that does this output. It is just telling you that the linking process is not seeing any of the compiled source above. In other words: This has nothing to do with *compilation* as you say. This is the linking process, which is broken.

Comment: Did you use a Makefile and type `make` - if so, you need to show the Makefile. Or did you type `clang ...` in which case, what was the full command?

Comment: As you tagged it `C++`, you probably need `clang++` instead of `clang`.

Comment: @KavehVahedipour I just use g++ main.cpp. Is this what you are asking about?

Comment: Well this is not enough, friend.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I just compile the main file using "g++ main.cpp". How do use clang++?

Comment: @KavehVahedipour Could you maybe give pointers on what should I be doing or where I can find what to do?

Comment: I have done exactly that below.

Comment: "actually a mathematician" - welcome to the dark arts of programming! Did you manage to get the "hello world" program compiling on your Mac?

Comment: If there are multiple `*.cpp` files in your project, you'll need to either compile them each separately and put them in a library and then link to them so that `main` can find them, or compile all your `*.cpp` files all together every time `g++ main.cpp fred.cpp frog.cpp hamiltonian.cpp -o main`. If there is a file called `Makefile`, just type `make`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks a lot. This solves the issue. A conceptual issue - why don't all the included files get compiled automatically when one compiles the main file (that would seem logical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to link something like this in the linking step:

```
g++ main.cpp gaussien.o hamiltonian_full.o ... xxx.o -o main
```

I assume that you have already compiled those object files. You really should make youself a `Makefile` for the whole process.

Oh btw, the same linker error you will see under Linux, I you just run `g++ main.cpp`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue. I did not know that somehow all the cpp files need to be compiled. I thought that if I run the master file, all the included files automatically get compiled. But apparently this is not the case.

Comment: It'd be awesome, if you accepted the answer. :)